# PHP dynamic variable creation via a getter

Tags: php, dynamic, reflection

So I'm working with a bag class, and I'm trying to dynamically create variables from the bag class.

Here's what I have:

```
class BagFoo
{
    public $a;
    public $b;
    public $c;
}
class Bar
{
    private $bagFoo;
    public function output()
    {
        foreach($this->bagFoo as $key => $value)
        {
            $$key = $value;
        }
        //output then happens here.
    }
}
```

This allows me to call $a instead of `$this->bagFoo->getA();` which I rather like, but the problem is I have to expose the member variables to implement it. I'd like to have the same dynamic variable assignment, but access the member variables through a getter, instead of accessing directly.

Solutions I've though of and didn't really like:

1. Having a `getVars()` function in `BagFoo` that would return an array of var names and their values, and then iterating through that.
2. Calling `get_class_methods()` and then doing parsing and iterating through the getters (ew).

I'm sure there's a way to do what I'm trying in a more elegant form, but I just can't think of how to implement it.

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/php-dynamic-variables.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code would probably be more understandable if you just used an associative array to store your values.

```
class Bar
{
    private $bagFoo = [];
    public function __construct($arr)
    {
        $this->bagFoo = $arr;

        foreach($arr as $key => $value)
        {
            $$key = $value;
        }
        echo $a; //echos 'aaaa'
    }
}
$bar = new Bar([
    'a' => 'aaaa',
    'b' => 'bbbb',
    'c' => 'cccc'
]);
```

Word of advice: **Be very careful using $$** because you can overwrite variables in the current scope and cause all kinds of problems in your application. For example:

```
$bar = new Bar([
    '_SERVER' => 'broken server vars!',
    '_COOKIE' => 'broken cookies!',
    'arr' => 'broken iterator!',
]);
```